# Python: Changing values in a String with a for loop

Tags: python

I am trying to build a caesar cipher in python, so I am trying to loop through the string and change the characters.

```
def caesar_shift(s, n):
  letters = list(s)
  for x in letters:
      if x == ' ':
          continue
      x = ord(x)
      x += n
      while (97 < x < 122) != True:
        if x < 97:
          x += 26
        elif x > 122:
          x -= 26
  letters = ''.join(letters)  
  return letters
print caesar_shift('a',1)
```

My output shows that x changes to 98, then turns into a 'b', but when the actual string is printed, all it shows is the letter 'a'. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` is a local variable within the loop and isn't changing the value of the element in the array.

You need to assign the new value of `x` back into the array like so:

```
for i,x in enumerate(letters):
    # ... rest of your loop
    letters[i] = x
```

From the Python documentation for the [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) function:

> Return an enumerate object. sequence must be a sequence, an iterator,
>   or some other object which supports iteration. The next() method of
>   the iterator returned by enumerate() returns a tuple containing a
>   count (from start which defaults to 0) and the values obtained from
>   iterating over sequence:
>
> ```
> >>> seasons = ['Spring', 'Summer', 'Fall', 'Winter']
> >>> list(enumerate(seasons))
> [(0, 'Spring'), (1, 'Summer'), (2, 'Fall'), (3, 'Winter')]
> >>> list(enumerate(seasons, start=1))
> [(1, 'Spring'), (2, 'Summer'), (3, 'Fall'), (4, 'Winter')]
> ```

Comment: Wow thanks so much! Could you explain how this works with the enumerate?

Comment: @user2909227 Linked and added the documentation for enumerate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
def encrypt(s,n):
  letters=list(s)
  cipher=[]
  for x in letters:
    if x==' ':
      continue
    else:
      p=ord(x)+n
      if(p>122):
        p=p-25
      cipher.append(chr(p))
  return cipher
print encrypt('abcde',1)
```